# Cannot reshape image into 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, classification, reshape

I am trying to reshape an image into a long 2d array (nrow * ncol, nband) with the following code:

```
new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2] - 1)

img_as_array = img[:, :, :7].reshape(new_shape)
print('Reshaped from {o} to {n}'.format(o=img.shape,
                                        n=img_as_array.shape))
```

The resulting error is the following:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-9de646941a34> in <module>
      2 new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2] - 1)
      3 
----> 4 img_as_array = img[:, :, :7].reshape(new_shape)
      5 print('Reshaped from {o} to {n}'.format(o=img.shape,
      6                                         n=img_as_array.shape))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 71696520 into shape (17924130,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your error, you have `nband == 4` in your original image, but in your `new_shape` variable `nband == 3` as you subtract one from it. so the size for reshape don't match. You can solve with one of this solutions depending on your problem.

```
new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]) # 1. don't subtract
```

or

```
img_as_array = img[:, :, :4].reshape(new_shape) # 2. make nband of image smaller
```